# How EXACTLY return statement works

Tags: javascript, return

Why does this NOT work in Javascript:

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {    
var min = Math.min(...numbers);  
return numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1);
}
```

but this DOES???

```
function removeSmallest(numbers) {
  var min = Math.min(...numbers);
  numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1); 
  return numbers;
}
```

I am really confused about the return statement besides knowing that I need it.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: The problem is not `return`. The problem is `splice()`. Read the docs **CAREFULLY** and understand how `splice()` works

Comment: I feel like I am using splice() in the exact same way here so I don't see the difference

Comment: Ohh I see, in the first one I am returning the splice array not numbers

Comment: To explain it in simple words: `splice()` is a method that loops through the array. On each loop, it "returns" the result. So you basically are trying to return a running loop.

Comment: So I am getting an array of [min] vs an array of [everything else] is that correct?

Comment: A lot of methods work like that and you can return them on the same line

Comment: splice returns what was removed. So the second function returns the changed array, but the 1st returns what was deleted from it.

Answer (score 2):

Both of the functions you've written are valid javascript, and in fact, there's a third variant that doesn't even use a return statement. If you're splicing on the array you passed in, you already have the resulting array. Consider:

```js
function removeSmallest1(numbers) {    
  var min = Math.min(...numbers);  
  return numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1);
}

function removeSmallest2(numbers) {    
  var min = Math.min(...numbers);  
  numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1);
  return numbers;
}

function removeSmallest3(numbers) {    
  var min = Math.min(...numbers);  
  numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1);
}

let args1 = [1, 3, 5, 7];
let args2 = [1, 3, 5, 7];
let args3 = [1, 3, 5, 7];

console.log("function1 input:", JSON.stringify(args1), "output:", JSON.stringify(removeSmallest1(args1)));
console.log("function2 input:", JSON.stringify(args2), "output:", JSON.stringify(removeSmallest2(args2)));
console.log("function3 input:", JSON.stringify(args3), "output:", JSON.stringify(removeSmallest3(args3)));

console.log("After calling functions, original arrays:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(args1)); // [3, 5, 7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(args2)); // [3, 5, 7]
console.log(JSON.stringify(args3)); // [3, 5, 7]
```

Note that in each case, the original array is modified by calling the function on it. The difference in return value is due to how [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) works in Javascript. From the documentation, the return value of splice is:

> An array containing the deleted elements.
> If only one element is removed, an array of one element is returned.
> If no elements are removed, an empty array is returned.

By calling `return numbers.splice(numbers.indexOf(min), 1)` you are telling the function to return the value returned by `splice`.